# How should I handle unwanted edits to my answer?

Tags: discussion

Today another user edited my answer for formatting, and in my opinion, made it worse. I can manually revert the changes of course, but there are several dozen. Is there an option to just rollback the edit? I see that option for my own edits, but not for this one. Is there a better way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 11):

I found the answer - the "rollback" option on old edits means "rollback to this edit" - I am used to DVCS where "rollback" means "undo."

So, to revert an edit, just find a previous edit and select "rollback" to return to that state.

Comment: "Rollback" means to undo edits to revert to a prior version.  Stackoverflow _is_ using the DVCS definition.